# Keep track of indentation-based state with flip-flop operator

Tags: perl

I am trying to get familiar with the flip-flop operator, so I can have it as an additional abstraction in my head when doing stateful looping, even though a textbook-style state machine works perfectly well (and verbose and variable-rich) in such a case. I want to keep track of indentation and it seems like I'd still need to manually adjust indentation at the start of every if block in whose condition I call my indenting flip-flop, right?
Here's what I came up with:

**Program**:

```
use v5.20;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $shiftwidth = 3;

# block_rx: start of indented block marker, without leading spaces
# Keeps state of indentation, which is increased on encountering block marker
# and decreased on matching outdent.
# Function should always get indentation level from context it was called in.
# Returns: true if in indented block, ^ff^, else false

sub indenting_flipflop {
    my $block_rx = $_[0];
    $_ = $_[1];
    my $level = $_[2];
    my $indent = indent($level);
    my $inner_indent = indent($level + 1);
    return ((/^$indent$block_rx/) ... (!/^$inner_indent/)) =~ s/.*E//r;
}

sub indent {
    return ' ' x ($shiftwidth * $_[0]);
}

while (<DATA>) {
    my $level = 0;
    if (indenting_flipflop('books', $_, $level)) {
        $level++;
        if (indenting_flipflop('book', $_, $level)) {
            $level++;
            if (/author: (.*)/) {
              say $1;
            }
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
books:
   book:
      author: Mark Twain
      price: 10.99
   game:
      author: Klaus Teuber
      price: 15.99
   book:
      author: Jane Austen
      price: 12.00

books:
   book:
      author: Mark Twain
      price: 10.99
   game:
      author: Klaus Teuber
      price: 15.99
   book:
      author: Jane Austen
      price: 12.00
```

**Expected output**:

```
Mark Twain
Jane Austen
Mark Twain
Jane Austen
```

**Actual output**:

```
Mark Twain
Klaus Teuber
Jane Austen
Mark Twain
Klaus Teuber
Jane Austen
```

It would also be nice, if I wouldn't have to adjust `$level` manually in the loop.

Comment: use strict and warnings?  initialize level to 0?  anchor the flipflop left operand regex?

Comment: @ysth: Sorry, I fixed these issues now and made my question clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flip-flop operators with dynamic operands are tricky to use and may not do what you expect. Perl maintains a single "state" for each flip-flop operator that appears in the code, not a separate state for each expression supplied as operands to the flip-flop operator.

Consider this code:

```
sub foo { m[<foo>] .. m[</foo>] }
sub bar { m[<bar>] .. m[</bar>] }

while (<DATA>) {    
    print "FOO:$_" if foo();
    print "BAR:$_" if bar();
}    
__DATA__
<foo>
   <bar>
      123
   </bar>
   <baz>
       456
   </baz>
</foo>
```

The output is:

```
FOO:<foo>
FOO:   <bar>
BAR:   <bar>
FOO:      123
BAR:      123
FOO:   </bar>
BAR:   </bar>
FOO:   <baz>
FOO:       456
FOO:   </baz>
FOO:</foo>
```

So far, so good, right? This approach won't scale well when there are 100 different tags to track instead of two, so let's try this code:

```
sub ff { my $tag = shift; m[<$tag>] .. m[</$tag>] }
while (<DATA>) {
    print "FOO:$_" if ff("foo");
    print "BAR:$_" if ff("bar");
}
__DATA__
<foo>
   <bar>
      123
   </bar>
   <baz>
       456
   </baz>
</foo>
```

Now the output is

```
FOO:<foo>
BAR:<foo>
FOO:   <bar>
BAR:   <bar>
FOO:      123
BAR:      123
FOO:   </bar>
BAR:   </bar>
```

What happened? `BAR` is always printed with the same lines as `FOO`, and the last line of output is the `</bar>` line, even though there is more data still enclosed in `<foo></foo>` tags.

What happened is that the code contains a single flip-flop operator, defined in the `ff` subroutine, and this operator maintains a single state. The state changes to "true" when `ff("foo")` is called with the first line of input, and it remains "true" until it encounters input and an operand that satisfies the second expression in the flip-flop operator, which happens with the 4th line when `ff("bar")` is called. It is not maintaining separate state for `foo` tags and `bar` tags as the first example did.

Passing different input to the `indenting_flipflop` function and expecting the flip-flop operator in that function to just operate on that kind of input will not work.

---

**Update**: so this approach, defining a single new function for each tag, works:

```
sub fff { my $tag = shift; sub { m[<$tag>] .. m[</$tag>] } }
my $foo = fff("foo");
my $bar = fff("bar");
while (<DATA>) {
    print "FOO:$_" if $foo->();
    print "BAR:$_" if $bar->();
}
__DATA__
...
```

but this one (defining new functions with every line of input) does not:

```
sub fff { my $tag = shift; sub { m[<$tag>] .. m[</$tag>] } }
while (<DATA>) {
    print "FOO:$_" if fff("foo")->();
    print "BAR:$_" if fff("bar")->();
}
__DATA__
...
```

On the other other hand a memoized version of it would work:

```
my %FF;
sub fff { my $tag = shift; $FF{$tag} //= sub { m[<$tag>] .. m[</$tag>] } }
while (<DATA>) {
    print "FOO:$_" if fff("foo")->();
    print "BAR:$_" if fff("bar")->();
}
__DATA__
...
```

I'm still not convinced that flip-flop operators would add any value to this problem, but to find out you would have to use memoized flip-flop operator generating functions. Replace

```
...
return ((/^$indent$block_rx/) ... (!/^$inner_indent/)) =~ s/.*E//r;
```

with

```
my %FF;
sub flipflopfunc {
    my ($expr1,$expr2) = @_;
    return $FF{$expr1}{$expr2} //= 
        sub { /^$expr1/ ... !/^$expr2/ };
}
...
return flipflopfunc("$indent$block_rx",$inner_indent)->() =~ s/.*E//r;
```

(not sure what the `s/.*E//r` is for)

Comment: flipflop's string return value ends 'E0' when the flop condition was met; see https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=525406 (but I'm not sure how that plays into OP's solution)

Comment: note that just a new anonymous function is not enough; it has to be a closure (refer to at least one external lexical) to get its own flipflop state data (at least that's my recollection)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still reading through it and first let me say that I used the `s/.*E//r`, because I figured that's the easiest way to make the end value return false ("0") and thereby exclude it, as I want the inner conditions in the while loop to only match while the lines are still indented.

Comment: That works, really cool! In your last code paragraph it still has to be three dots, so `sub { /^$expr1/ ... !/^$expr2/ }`, and then it directly works.

Comment: Ok, I'll change back to `...`